# Terence Tao Analysis I proposition 5.5.12

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

On page 120 of Terence Tao's *Analysis I, 3rd Ed.*, there's one step I cannot understand in showing the **Proposition 5.5.12** *There exists a positive real number $x$ such that
$x^2 = 2$*:

T. Tao started with arguing by contradiction and considered two assumptions $x^2 < 2$ and $x^2 > 2$, which both should lead to contradictions.

Taking the first assumption, given that $x^2 < 2$ (from hypothesis) and $x \le 2$ (due to 2 being an upper bound), why can we get some $0 < \epsilon < 1$ such that $x^2 + 5\epsilon < 2$ holds? There is a similar trick for the case where $x^2 > 2$ (see the below link) but I believe understanding the aforementioned one should be enough for explaining both.

This link is [the complete proof taken from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KGEO.png), in which you can see I underlined the step confuses me

Comment: Use the Archimedean property to choose a positive integer $n$ such that $\tfrac{1}{n} < \tfrac{2 - x^2}{5}$ (possible because $2 - x^2 > 0$). Then $\epsilon = \tfrac{1}{n}$ does the trick.

Comment: @LewisMacRae Brilliant! Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon := \frac{2- x^2}{10} > 0$. Then $$x^2 + 5 \epsilon = x^2 + \frac{2 - x^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + 1 < \frac{2}{2} + 1 = 2,$$ since not only $x^2 \leq 2$, $x^2 < 2.$

Comment: Nice work! Thx!